# Windows system service hosting webserver on port 5357

Tags: windows

I was just looking through my windows system and I found that there was a web server running on port 5357 (127.0.0.1:5357). The name of the process is system and the web page just returns a 503 when I view it, but that's all I know. Any ideas on what this may be?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you share folders on the local network? If so you can disable this.

**All you have to do is go to:**

*Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings*

**Then you have to disable Network Discovery for any public network and done know I think the port is unmapped. I hope I could help you with that.**

Comment: I did that but the web server's still up. I added some more info to the question

Comment: Ok I have also used port 5357 so it seems normal I have tested it on a just reinstalled system so that should be a default Windows port for any kind of service dont know.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help. I'm not really too concerned about it just curious as it has not always been there.